# Как при изменении ролей пользователя сразу же перечитывать их

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, role

Доступ к контроллеру имеют лишь пользователи с ролью "admin":

```
namespace ASPMVC.Controllers
{
    [Authorize(Roles ="admin")]   
    public class AirplaneController : Controller
    {
    }
}
```

Обращаюсь с аккаунта без роли, приложение не пускает:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После устанавливаю роль "admin":[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но приложение снова отказывает в доступе:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если же перезапустить приложение, то доступ появляется.
Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы при изменении роли пользователь мог обращаться к контроллеру без перезапуска приложения?

Метод изменения ролей пользователя в RoleController:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string userId, List<string> roles)
    {            
        UserDop userDop = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        if (userDop != null)
        {
            var userRoles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(userDop);
            var allRoles = roleManager.Roles.ToList();
            var addedRoles = roles.Except(userRoles);
            var removedRoles = userRoles.Except(roles);

            await userManager.AddToRolesAsync(userDop, addedRoles);
            await userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(userDop, removedRoles);
            return RedirectToAction("UserList");
        }
        return NotFound();
    }
```

Comment: Видимо под "перезапустить приложение" понимается не остановка приложения в Visual Studio и его новый запуск (у меня при этом пользователь как был залогинен, так и остаётся) - а именно перезапуск приложения на IIS. Насколько я понимаю, все сессии по умолчанию хранятся в InProc (и топикстартер не менял этот режим) и при рестарте приложения сессии сбрасываются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Я пожалуй рискну опубликовать ответом, хотя это скорее указание
>   направления или идея, чем полноценный ответ. Если кто-то имеет опыт и
>   хочет указать на недостатки - пишите в комментариях, а не ставьте
>   молча минусы. Или опубликуйте свою версию ответа, мне тоже любопытно
>   будет глянуть.

Вы написали свой кастомный контроллер+экшн Role/Edit в котором пользователю можно поменять список ролей.

Нужно в этом месте добавить разлогинивание и залогинивание пользователя, которому вы поменяли права. Как легко это было бы, если это был [текущий пользователь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35446038/5752652)!

Первое направление я вижу вот какое. Переключаете приложение на [использование сессий в SQL сервер](http://www.cyberguru.ru/microsoft-net/asp-net/aspnet-session-exploration.html?showall=1) и пробегаетесь по всем сессиям, десериализуя [SessionItemShort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478952.aspx) и меняя нужные. (Я правда сам никогда не пробовал сам десериализовать эти данные, так что тут ещё нужно изучить вопрос, как это делать - ну и сама возможность неочевидна)

Плюсы этого направления: данные сессий менять непросто, но это делается единожды в момент смены ролей.

Второе направление я вижу вот какое. Создаёте <s>в классе ApplicationUser  дополнительное поле HasRoleChanged</s> и создаёте самописный Handler, который будет при каждом http-запросе сравнивать список текущих ролей (они в сессии) со списком ролей записанных в базе. Реализовать значительно проще ([пример можно посмотреть тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35221022/5752652)), но дёргать базу получая роли на каждый http-запрос не очень гуманно.

Comment: Список ролей пользователя не в сессии же хранится...

Comment: @PavelMayorov А где тогда? Насколько я понимаю - хранятся они в базе, но перечитываются только при каждом очередном входе в систему. Либо - при перезапуске IIS сбрасывается всё хранилище сессий (которое в памяти). Я что-то не так понимаю в механизме работы identity? PS Открыл приложение, отрыл SQL профайлер на базе. Долго ходил по страницам неавторизованным, все чисто. В момент когда решил залогиниться увидел портянку запросов (от чтения миграций до SELECT TOP(1) FROM Users WHERE login = кто авторизовался, потом получение Claims, ролей). Потом ходил авторизованным - снова тихо в запросах к БД.

Comment: @AK большое спасибо за варианты решения проблемы. Первое для меня, как начинающего разработчика не очень понятно, второе - сам понимаю, не гуманно. Пойду по пути наименьшего сопротивления и укажу роль admin заранее созданным аккаунтам разработчиков (себе) без возможности изменения (оно, в принципе, и не нужно). Ещё раз большое спасибо)

Comment: @AK в токене авторизации вроде же. В ASP.NET это отдельная кука.